# Mongoose Schema.method() is not working, and showing an error message

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am taking password input from the user and encrypting the password using crypto, then saving into the database. This is my code, here I am storing the encrypted password into the encry_password property that comes from the userSchema. But, this is giving me error that "this.securePassword" is not a function.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const { v1: uuidv1 } = require("uuid");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 32,
    trim: true,
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 32,
    trim: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  usrinfo: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  encry_password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  salt: String,
  role: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  purchases: {
    type: Array,
    default: [],
  },
}, { timestamps: true });


userSchema.virtual("password")
  .set((password) => {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = uuidv1();
    this.encry_password = securePassword(password, uuidv1());
    console.log(this.encry_password);
  })
  .get(() => {
    return this._password;
  });

// const authenticate = function (plainPassword, encry_password) {
//   return securePassword(plainPassword) === encry_password;
//   };

const securePassword = function (plainPassword, salt) {
  if (!plainPassword) return "";
  try {
    return crypto.createHmac("sha256", salt).update(plainPassword).digest("hex");
  } catch (error) {
    return "";
  }
};


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Route for user signup

```
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const user = new User(req.body);
    user.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400).json({
                err: "Note able to save the user in database"
            });
        } else {
            res.json(user);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, in this situation you shouldn't use `virtual`

[Virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals)

> Virtuals are document properties that you can get and set but that do not get persisted to MongoDB. The getters are useful for formatting or combining fields, while setters are useful for de-composing a single value into multiple values for storage.

but in the scope of `virtual`, `this` cannot access to method, you can not access to the method like your manner, it's a example of method usage in mongoose

```
  const Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);
  const dog = new Animal({ type: 'dog' });

  dog.findSimilarTypes((err, dogs) => {
    console.log(dogs); // woof
  });
```

you can check the [method documantation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods):

if you want just access to `securePassword` in your manner you can like this and delete method mongoose complately because this is not the place to use `method`:

```
UserSchema.virtual("password")
  .set((password) => {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = uuidv1();
    console.log("This is running");
    this.encry_password = securePassword(password, this.salt);
    console.log(encry_password);
  })
  .get(() => {
    return this._password;
  });

const authenticate = function (plainPassword, encry_password) {
  return securePassword(plainPassword) === encry_password;
};

const securePassword = function (plainPassword, salt) {
  if (!plainPassword) return "";
  try {
    return crypto
      .createHmac("sha256", salt)
      .update(plainPassword)
      .digest("hex");
  } catch (error) {
    return "";
  }
};
```

if you want to create `authenticate service`, change your manner, and don't use virtual for password and use `pre save`

before saving information about users in db this tasks will be done
check the [pre documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre)

```
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  try {
    this.password = securePassword (plainPassword, salt);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

after created a hash password save informations like this :

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    .
    .
    .
    password: { //convert encry_password to password
      type: String,
    }
    .
    .
    .
  }, { timestamps: true });
  //every time want to user save this method called
  userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.salt = uuidv1()
    this.password = securePassword(this.password, this.salt)
    next()
 })
 //for have a clean  routes, you can create a static methods
 userSchema.statics.Create = async (data) => {
    let model = new User(data); 
    let resUser = await model.save(); //save your user
    return resUser;
  };

  const securePassword = function (plainPassword, salt) {
    if (!plainPassword) return "";
    try {
      return crypto.createHmac("sha256", salt).update(plainPassword).digest("hex");
    } catch (error) {
      return "";
    }
  };
  
  let User  = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
  module.exports = {User};
```

change controller like this :

```
let {User} = require("./path of user schema")
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    const user = await User.create(req.body); //create a user
    res.json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json({
      err: "Note able to save the user in database",
    });
  }
};
```

**NOTE** : in req.body, name of password field, should be `password`

Comment: I run this code, it's working fine and am able to store encrypted password in this.encry_password property. But, the problem is that before storing the password in this.encry_password property, the null information is being saved in database, that's why it's throwing an error "this.encry_password is required".

Comment: please added your schema file completely to the question

Comment: you should change your manner, and don't use virtual, in `virtual` scope can not access to schema fields with `this`, use `pre save`,

Comment: I have added my whole schema file, you can check now

Comment: you want create a user with hash password? is it right?

Comment: Yes, I want to do exactly.

Comment: added route (controller) to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227600/discussion-between-akash-kanaujiya-and-mohammad-yaser-ahmadi).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the scope of the securePassword function is defined inside userSchema, and you're trying to call it in userSchema.virtual.

Comment: Can you help me to fix this problem?